# Problems with recursive backtracking algorithm for a 3D maze

Tags: maze, recursion

The algorithm really shines when craving process get's stuck (only visited nodes around), then it backtracks and creates alternative routes for the maze. That's kind of the point of a maze, that there are different paths and you can take wrong or right one. When I add extra dimensions (3rd one) to the algorithm to create a 3D maze, it almost never gets stuck because there are so much directions now to go and for most it's just one way path. I wonder if there is some trick to fix this or maybe I need different algorithm?

Comment: Have you considered a spanning tree algorithm? ([See a selection about 3/4 of the way down here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/))

Comment: I have been looking into Kruskal’s algorithm, Prim’s algorithm, recursive division algorithm, Growing Tree algorithm (http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/27/maze-generation-growing-tree-algorithm) - not sure if it's not same as spanning tree.

Comment: Great! How have you tried putting them into practice? Any specific issues we can help you solve?

Comment: Haven't yet put to practice any other than recursive backtracking. I'm a bit lost now as there is so much algorithms. No idea where to start.

Comment: One maze generation algorithm I like is the [recursive subdivision algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method). I haven't tried, but I think it should work fine for more than two dimension.

Comment: @Philipp yeah, read above comment. It's on my radar. One negative aspect of it is, that it tends to create lot's of 'single chamber rooms'

Comment: So, can you edit your question to clarify what specific step you need our help with? If it's just which algorithm to use, and you have several that look equally-promising in your evaluation, just roll a die and make a start based on that. If you run into a specific problem along the way we can help you solve, edit your question to describe that problem.